# What normalisation form is a restaurant menu?

Tags: sql, database-normalization

This is probably off-topic but I'm curious.

Say you have a normal restaurant menu with an itemID, meal name and price. What normal form is it?

I say it's BCNF because but a friend brought up that it isn't in 3NF because of transitive dependency price -> item name -> item number. What do you guys think?

Comment: It doesn't have any normal form. It's a *restaurant menu*.

Comment: Don't start your question with "This is probably off-topic"

Comment: Are `itemID` and meal name both candidate keys?

Comment: Depends on things likes whether you want to cope with same meal at different prices. As in previous price, breakfast special etc. With your design if you did want that you would be repeating meal. Think about what would happen if you had a recipe table as well. Not enough content for you. me or your mate to say right or wrong

Comment: no deals; just a restaurant menu. Yes itemID and meal name are both candidate keys.

Comment: In my experience a 'normal' restaurant menu doesn't have an `itemID`. An 'ethnic' food take-away menu does but that's to assist with telephone orders where the customer can't point to the item they cannot pronounce. If a restaurant's menu included had `itemID` values then I wouldn't eat there, ditto pictures of individual dishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A restaurant menu isn't in any normal form. As with any other set of requirements, a menu could be represented either as a relation schema in BCNF or as some other schema not in BCNF. That's a choice the database designer makes when he creates the schema; not something implicit in the menu information itself.

You haven't exactly specified the schema in question. Assuming the relation:

```
Menu {ItemID, Name, Price}
```

with two keys: {ItemID} and {Name} then Menu is in BCNF with respect to the set of functional dependencies:

```
ItemID -> Name -> Price
Name -> ItemID -> Price
```

These are not non-key transitive dependencies because both Name and ItemID are candidate keys. Since Menu is in BCNF it is also in 3NF.

Functional dependencies are always written in the form Determinant -> Dependant. I don't see how Price would ever be likely to be a determinant (a unique price for every item on the menu seems extremely unlikely) so the dependency you mentioned: price -> item name -> item number doesn't make much sense to me. If price did happen to be a non-key determinant for some reason then the above Menu relation would of course violate BCNF (and 3NF).

Comment: thanks sqlvogel. However I'm still confused: why is ItemID -> Name -> Price (which is what I meant about the determinant - thanks for clearing that up too!) not transitive dependency? Price is dependent on Name which is dependent on Item ID. 3NF states that no attribute can be transitively dependent on the primary key. Here, price is clearly violating it.

Comment: That is not a *non-key* transitive dependency because both determinants are superkeys. It is *non-key* transitive dependencies which are not permitted under BCNF. Normal Forms have no special requirements about dependence on any one "primary" key. BCNF treats all candidate keys (and by implication therefore all superkeys) equally. ItemID->Name->Price simply means that Price is dependent on both keys, which is exactly what we want and expect under BCNF.

Comment: coming back to this question, what do you mean by "That is not a non-key transitive dependency because both determinants are superkeys. It is non-key transitive dependencies which are not permitted under BCNF"?

Comment: A functional dependency violates BCNF if and only if it is non-trivial and the left-hand side of the dependency is not a superkey. Therefore if Name is a superkey then BCNF is not violated by Name->Price or Name->ItemId. If Name is not a superkey then BCNF is violated.

Answer (score 2):

If the menu is in one language only, then the table has two keys (id and name) and every non-key (price) is dependent on every key, satisfying 3NF. 4NF is also satisfied, since there is only one non-key column. 5NF and 6NF take care of multi-table relations; since there is only one table, they are satisfied too.

If the menu is multilingual, the menu still satisfies first normal form (if we consider the virtual column "language" as a true column; otherwise, the menu is not even 1NF), but fails to satisfy the second normal form: no non-key attribute is dependent on a proper subset of a key:
The schema here is: columns(language,id,name,price); keys((language,id),(name[,language])) but price is dependent on the meal ID only, not the language it was ordered in.

DB-theoretically, the proper decomposition would be to introduce a pair of tables
table(language,id,name) keys((language,id),(name[,language]))
table(id,price) keys(id)
. Of course, this would be inconvenient at a real restaurant (imagine getting two menus - an english menu and a translation table) and the only benefit would be the independence of price on language is enforced rather than implied.

There is no dependence of the name on the price: the price does not determine the name; it is the opposite way.

Comment: Good answer Jan, but still, price -> name -> ID not a transitive dependency? You know what I mean...

Also, the menu is in English

Comment: Lastly, you are wrong because ID and name is a superkey; primary keys must be minimal, in this case ID is the primary key.

Comment: "6NF [is] satisfied too" -- are you sure? "a regular relvar is in 6NF if and only if it consists of a single key, plus at most one additional attribute" -- [Database in Depth: Relational Theory for Practitioners By C. J. Date](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FU7uuHc3oNcC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=6nf+key+plus+one+attribute&source=bl&ots=RsUb39QBGp&sig=SnY332OnO72Hg9bnO58TUqfzryE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=20ieT8CwMcKfOsDk9fsB&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=6nf%20key%20plus%20one%20attribute&f=false)